# Need Help. Trying to create new list item every button clicked with new text

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android. I'm trying to create so that every button "saveBtn" clicked, a new item will show in list.

MainActivity.java

```
    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> NotesAdapter;
    ArrayList<NotesID> Notes;

.....

      list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Notes = new ArrayList<NotesID>();
        NotesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Notes);

        title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        int imageResourceId = getIntent().getIntExtra("imageNote", 0);
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.noteIcon);
        if (imageResourceId != 0) {
            imageView.setImageResource(imageResourceId);}
//            Notes.add("" + title);
        Notes.add(new NotesID("title"));

            list.setAdapter(NotesAdapter);
            NotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

newNote.java

```
ublic class newNote extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton saveBtn;
    EditText newNoteTitle;
    EditText newNotetxt;
    String title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_note);

        saveBtn = findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        newNoteTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newNoteTitle);
        newNotetxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newNotetxt);

//        title = newNoteTitle.getText().toString();

        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                int imageResourceId = R.drawable.ic_newnote;
                title = newNoteTitle.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(newNote.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("title", title);
//                i.putExtra("imageNote", imageResourceId);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

NotesID.java

```
public class NotesID {
    private String title;

    public NotesID(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String text) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

I know how to create just one line in a list, which is what I want. But I can't manage to create a second, third and etc lines of list.

Comment: Please don't put tags (like `(Android)`) in the title. That is what question tags are for.

Comment: `Notes.add(new NotesID("title"));` Add more notes by adding more to the `Notes` `ArrayList`. Then notify the adapter the dataset has changed